# Don't clear the framebuffer when exiting pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've written a small script to display album art on USB display (on Raspberry Pi) by writing to the framebuffer with `pygame`. The script is working perfectly and the album art is displayed on the screen for 3 seconds:

```
def set_image(image):
    """ Set the USB display image using pygame (320px x 240px) """
    pygame.display.init()
    size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
    black = 0, 0, 0
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    pygame_image = pygame.image.fromstring(image.tobytes(), image.size, image.mode)
    pygame_image_rect = pygame_image.get_rect()
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(pygame_image, (40, 0))
    pygame.font.init()
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(3)
```

The problem is that when the script finishes, `pygame` (correctly) clears the framebuffer and my image disappears. Is there any way to tell it to leave the contents of the framebuffer when quitting?

Comment: How do you know `pygame` is clearing the framebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling pygame.quit?

Generally:
 - don't run window server (run from console)
 - use flip to flip to a different surface 
 - don't call pygame.quit when exiting.

It is hard to guarantee what happens after that, but flip should flip the screen buffer to a different part of memory than the shell uses, so it won't get overwritten, and if you don't call pygame.quit, it should leave it in the (bad) state. Although there are scenarios this is useful.

Comment: "When the Python interpreter shuts down, this method is called regardless, so your program should not need it"